# Comm argument on MPI_Reduce in FORTRAN giving unusual results

Tags: fortran, mpi

I'm putting together a very simple integration program in FORTRAN using MPI.  I have done this with C and all was well.

However, in my "MAP_REDUCE" call, the comm argument seems problematic.  I have tried several different values and have gotten several error messages when the program runs.

Note:  the program does compile, but does not run.

Here is the program itself (FORTRAN 90):

```
  c Fortran example                                                      
  program intega
  implicit none
  include '/opt/apps/intel15/mvapich2/2.1/include/mpif.h'

  integer rank,size,ierror,tag,status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE),i
  real :: integral = 0.00, x = 0.00, total_t = 0.00
  real :: analy,numres,edif


  real, PARAMETER :: x_lower_bound = 0,x_upper_bound = 1
  real, PARAMETER :: nsteps = 10000000
  real, PARAMETER :: dx = (x_upper_bound - x_lower_bound)/nSteps


  integer :: iMin,iMax,ierr=0,comm=0


  call MPI_INIT(ierror)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,size,ierror)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierror)
  do i = 0,(iMax-1)
      x = x_lower_bound + dx*(i+0.5)
      integral = integral + x*x*dx
   end do

   call MPI_REDUCE(integral,total_t,1,MPI_REAL,MPI_SUM,0,rank,ierr)
   analy = ((x_upper_bound**3)-(x_lower_bound**3))/3
   numres = total_t

   if (rank == 0) then
      edif = analy-numres
      print *, numres,analy,edif
   end if


  call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
  end
```

Now the error file looks like this:  (not the whole thing, just a sample)

```
[cli_0]: [cli_1]: aborting job:
Fatal error in PMPI_Reduce:
Invalid communicator, error stack:
PMPI_Reduce(1288): MPI_Reduce(sbuf=0x6ac4a8, rbuf=0x6ac4b4, count=1, MPI_REAL, \
MPI_SUM, root=0, comm=0x1) failed
PMPI_Reduce(1163): Invalid communicator

aborting job:
Fatal error in PMPI_Reduce:
Invalid communicator, error stack:
PMPI_Reduce(1288): MPI_Reduce(sbuf=0x6ac4a8, rbuf=0x6ac4b4, count=1, MPI_REAL, \
MPI_SUM, root=0, comm=0x0) failed
PMPI_Reduce(1163): Invalid communicator

[cli_2]: aborting job:
Fatal error in PMPI_Reduce:
Invalid communicator, error stack:
```

So the communicator is the troublemaker.  But not sure what I should be putting in there instead.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MPI_Reduce` call doesn't have a valid communicator specified. I think you left it out entirely. The place where you have `rank` should be the same value everywhere you call it, and it should be a communicator. From the look of your code, it should be `MPI_COMM_WORLD` since every rank is doing the operation.

Comment: When using MPI from Fortran, it is highly recommended to use the `mpi_f08` module which will catch this sort of thing.